# Remove contacts from campaign using an apex class

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, contact, campaign, campaign-member

I'm having an issue trying to get contacts removed from a campaign. I think it may be because I'm looking for campaign members instead of contacts, but I'm not entirely sure. I have the class set to run every fifteen minutes, but they aren't being removed.

```
global class AlertCampaignRemoval implements Schedulable {
    DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
    //Switching campaign id to dev alert campaign, dont deploy without switching
    public List<CampaignMember> memberRemoved = [SELECT Id FROM CampaignMember WHERE CreatedDate > :dt.addMinutes(15) AND CampaignId =:'campaignId'];
    global void execute (SchedulableContext ctx) {
        if (memberRemoved != null && memberRemoved.size() > 0) {
            delete memberRemoved;
            System.debug('hit delete');
            System.debug(memberRemoved);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your query is you are looking for a `CreateDate`  in the future. Change `addMinutes(15)` to `addMinutes(-15)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query for Campaign Members should be in the execute method. I do believe that where you put it means it would run that query only when you first schedule the class, as opposed to every time it runs.